# Multivariate Skew Normal in Stan

Tags: distribution, stan, rstan

I'm trying to estimate a Bayesian hierarchical model in Rstan and would like to include in my model a multivariate skew normal distribution. This is not a distribution that is already defined in Stan, but the documentation seems to suggest that one could implement it using Cholesky factors. For example, the Stan 2.15.0 documentation says on pp. 333-334:

"This reparameterization of a multivariate normal distribution in terms of standard normal variates can be extended to other multivariate distributions that can be conceptualized as contaminations of the multivariate normal, such as the multivariate Student t and the skew multivariate normal distribution."

Does anyone have any idea how to actually do this? I considered implementing the skew multivariate normal myself in Stan, but it doesn't look like there is a nice closed form for the distribution that would lend itself to straightforward implementation...

Comment: I don't have Stan code, but this might help:  http://www.anstuocmath.ro/mathematics/pdf10/83_96_RVernic.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

So the `sn` package has the `rmsn` function that clearly shows the following section of code:

```
function (n = 1, xi = rep(0, length(alpha)), Omega, alpha, tau = 0, dp = NULL) {
//....
    lot <- dp2cpMv(dp = dp0, family = "SN", aux = TRUE)
    d <- length(dp0$alpha)
    y <- matrix(rnorm(n * d), n, d) %*% chol(lot$aux$Psi)
//....
}
```

This is very similar to how the `mvtnorm::rmvn` works just the matrix in `chol()` method comes from dp2cpMv function in the core library [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/sn/src/R/sn-funct.R). You can port that into your `functions{}` block. And in your stan program you go(I am assuming the cov matrix in `chol()` is a parameter)

```
functions {
     // Contains code for your ported cholesky factor
}
transformed parameters {
    matrix[K, J] z;
    cholesky_factor_corr[K] L_tri = dp2cvClone(...); // Cholesky factor from your function{} block..
    beta = foo + (L_tri * z)'; // Assuming foo is baseline parameter representing the mean of dimensionality J*K. 
....
}

parameters {
    matrix[K, J] beta; //# J levels/groups and K dimensional parameters 
    to_vector(z) ~ normal_pdf(0, 1); 
    .... 
}
```

Also you may want to shift stuff from transformed parameters block to data or transformed data block if the inputs to `dp2cvClone()` are data. But you get the point.
This last section of code is lifted from the stan manual `section 8.15` and paraphrased for brevity, and hopes to capture the important parts you need to make it work.